# How do I mimic android's preference widgets look?

Tags: android

I'm needing to write a custom "Settings page" that uses an expandablelistview.  Within each expandablelistview group, I would like to have rows (child views) appear just like Preference items in android (layout, style, etc.).

How can I make this happen?  Can I just rip the layout/style from some source code somewhere?

Edit:
It looks like here's the default preference layout file: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-5.0.0_r1/core/res/res/layout/preference.xml and android is able to use it simply by doing R.layout.preference at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v7/preference/src/android/support/v7/preference/Preference.java.

So now the question is, how do I use it?  android.R.Layout.preference isn't a valid layout...

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how.

Add this to your gradle build file: `compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:25.2.0'`

Then you can use `android.support.v7.preference.R.layout.preference` file.

Then just call addView on id widget_frame.